# Using serializer how to Create Category in django rest framework

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-views, django-serializer

I want to create category in django rest framework with serializer.
name will be provided from frontend input field.
I'm getting the user_id from  user = request.user and cafe_id from request.user.cafe.
I need to create category with name, user_id and cafe_id.
How can I do this?

here is the model

```
class Category(models.Model):
  user = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name="cat", blank=True, null=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
  cafe = models.ForeignKey(Cafe, related_name="category", blank=True, null=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
  name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
  
  class Meta:
    verbose_name_plural='Categories'
    
  def __str__(self):
    return self.name
```

Here is the serializer

```
class CategorySerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
  class Meta:
    model = Category
    fields = ['name']
```

and the views.py

```
@api_view(['POST'])
@permission_classes((IsAuthenticated,))
def categoryCreate(request):
  user = request.user
  user_id = Category(user = user)
  cafe = request.user.cafe
  cafe_id = Category(cafe = cafe)
  
  serializer = CategorySerializer(user_id, cafe_id, data=request.data)
  data={}
  if serializer.is_valid():
    serializer.save()
    data["success"] = "Category Has Been Created!"
    return Response(serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
  return Response(serializer.errors, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

Thank You In Advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can to this

```
class UserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
   class Meta:
      model = User
      fields = "__all__"

class CafeSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
   class Meta:
      model = Cafe
      fields = "__all__"

class CategorySerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
  user = UserSerializer(read_only=True)
  cade = CafeSerializer(read_only=True)
  class Meta:
    model = Category
    fields = ['name', 'user', 'cafe']
```